# Using Differential Equations to model path of satelite around earth

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, gmat

I am new to GMAT and am hoping to use it to model the path of a Low Earth Orbit satellite around Earth. I am thinking of plotting the path on a plane and using polar coordinates to model the path where the earth's center is the origin. My aim is to derive a differential equation through which I can know the satellite's exact location in space at any given time. How do I use GMAT's features to do that?

Comment: Why do you want a differential equation? Are you adding perturbation terms to your model? If so GMAT, should be able to address that for you without delving into the more complicated physics. You shouldn't also need to calculate the trajectory. GMAT does the propagation for you given an initial state.

Comment: Lagrange planetary equations: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestial/node149.html